# jQuery Ajax - Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, railo, cfml

I've broken my own jQuery Ajax update table :(

I'm pretty sure its how I'm referring to jQuery (I'm a javascript noob). 
I'm using Railo(CFML) with a bootstrap framework and the [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) plugin. I'm dynamically outputting the table and each cell within the table should be Ajax editable.

```
<cfoutput query="the_table">
    <tr id="gererated_table">

    <!--- Looping through and dynamicly displaying content rows of the table with ajax editing --->
    <cfloop array="#column_ids#" index="i" <!---  from="1" to="#howmany_cols.total_cols#" --->>
        <cfset colmun = "col#i#"> 
        <td><a class="ajax_update" name="#session.tblname#" data-name="col#i#" data-pk="#id#" data-type="text" data-url="ajax/ajax_textfield.cfm?table=#session.tblname#" data-thetable="#session.tblname#" data-placement="right" >#evaluate(colmun)#</a></td>
    </cfloop>

    <td><a href="table_row_delete.cfm?id=#any_tables.ID#&rowid=#id#" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Delete Row</a></td>

    </tr>
</cfoutput>
```

But after I click edit and submit, it then errors on my ajax page:

> ERROR: key [VALUE] doesn't exist in struct
>   (keys:id,fieldnames,col3,thetable)

Here is my jQuery snip at the bottom of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    // These start the Java Function for the inline table editing
    $('.ajax_update').editable({
        params: function(params) {  //params already contain `name`, `value` and `pk`
        var data = {};
        data['id'] = params.pk;
        data[params.name] = params.value;
        data ['thetable'] = "";
        return data;
    }
    });

    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

});
</script>
```

Comment: You should escape the jquery code too so it's easier to read :)

Comment: Your error message is a Railo one, and is fairly self explanatory - the `value` key doesn't exist where you're trying to use it, somewhere in the ajax page, which you've not posted the code for.

Comment: You're naming the value param `col3`, not value.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but if "the_table" query returns more than one record, you will have multiple 'tr' with an id of "gererated_table".